# Processing column with letters before feeding into a NN

Tags: pandas, neural-network, data-preprocessing

I wanted to implement a classification algorithm using NN but some columns have complex alphanumeric strings, so I just chose only the simpler columns to check. Here is an example with few elements of the columns I chose...
[Few Elements of the COL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRFaM.png)

As you can see these columns have **A,G,C or T**..etc. Some had combinations of the 4 letters but I removed it for now. My plan was to map each of these letters to values like **1,2,3 and 4** and then feed them to the NN.

Is this mapping **acceptable** for feeding into a dense NN?? Or is there any better method for doing this

Answer (score 0):

I would not map it to integers like 1, 2, 3 etc because you are mistakenly giving them a certain order or rank which the NN may capture as important, although this ranking does not truly exist.

If you do not have high cardinality (*many unique values*) then you can apply One-Hot Encoding. If the cardinality is high, then you should use other encoding techniques, otherwise one-hot encoder will introduce a lot of dimensionality to your data and sparsity, which are not welcomed. You can find here some other interesting [methods](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/08/types-of-categorical-data-encoding/) to encode categorical variables.